# Вложенная функция останавливающая выполнение основной

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
long validate_params(const Params& params, std::string& err)
{
   if (validate_rule1(params) == false)
   {
      err = "fail at rule 1";
      return -1;
   }
   ...
   if (validate_ruleN(params) == false)
   {
      err = "fail at rule N";
      return -1;
   }

   return 0; // success
}
```

Для улучшения читаемости кода пишем макрос, вроде такого:

```
#define RULE_ERROR(N) \ 
{\
   err = "fail at rule N"; \
   return -1; \
}
```

И тогда код станет выглядеть так:

```
long validate_params(const Params& params, std::string& err)
{
   if (validate_rule1(params) == false)
      RULE_ERROR(1);
   ...
   if (validate_ruleN(params) == false)
      RULE_ERROR(N);

   return 0; // success
}
```

Возможно ли реализовать подобное решение без макросов?

Comment: Да. `try`,  `throw` и `catch` изучите

Comment: решение на эксепшнах не может быть реализовано в виду древности проекта и сложности интеграции) объем кода ~50k строк подобного, чтобы это привести в чувство надо время, время - деньги, а денег никогда нет

Comment: Ну есть еще `setjmp/longjmp`, но в С++ это создаст больше проблем, чем решит...

Comment: В лямбду неплохо оборачивается

Comment: если где то появляется 1, 2, ... N, значит нужен массив (вектор). Дальше догадаетесь, @goldstar_labs ?

Comment: Не очень понятно, чего вы хотите тут добиться. Сделать `return` невидимыми? Так это крайне сомнительная затея. Упростить генерацию сообщения об ошибке? Так это можно спокойно вынести в функции проверки этих условий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Rule_error {
    string& s;    
public:
    Rule_error(string& er) : s(er) { }
    int operator ()(size_t n)
    {
        s += ' ';
        s += to_string(n);
        return -1;
    }
};

long validate_params(const Params& params, std::string& err)
{
    Rule_error r(err);
   if (validate_rule1(params) == false)
      return r(1);
   ...
   if (validate_ruleN(params) == false)
      return r(N);

   return 0; // success
}
```

Впринципе так тоже удобно

Comment: Это может сработать, спасибо.

Comment: Рад помочь, удачи!